# How to place text at a particular position outside the plot in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

I would like to write `\gamma` **on top of my legend** in the plot (shown in Image) generated by using the code shown below. I generally use `\node at (axis cs: co-ordinate x,co-ordinate y) {text}` of the plot. Since the legend is outside the plot, i am not sure how to access a point above the legend using `\node`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{loglogaxis}[
 %  scale=0.8,
 %  width=\columnwidth,
 %  baseline,
    ylabel={$G(\gamma,t) \:\: \mathrm{(Pa)}$},
    xlabel= t (s),
    legend entries ={0.1,0.2,0.4,0.8},
    legend style={at={(1.3,0.5)},anchor=east,font=\small},
]

\addplot [color=red,line width=1.5pt] table [x=time,y=m01,row sep=newline] {relaxationExpDatafor65v.dat};

\addplot [color=green,line width=1.5pt] table [x=time,y=m02,row sep=newline] {relaxationExpDatafor65v.dat};

\addplot [color=blue,line width=1.5pt] table [x=time,y=m04,row sep=newline] {relaxationExpDatafor65v.dat};

\addplot [color=cyan,line width=1.5pt] table [x=time,y=m08,row sep=newline] {relaxationExpDatafor65v.dat};


%%fits

\addplot [color=black,line width=1pt,densely dashed] table [x=time,y=m01,row sep=newline] {relaxationExpDataPredfor65v.dat};

\addplot [color=black,line width=1pt,densely dashed] table [x=time,y=m02,row sep=newline] {relaxationExpDataPredfor65v.dat};

\addplot [color=black,line width=1pt,densely dashed] table [x=time,y=m04,row sep=newline] {relaxationExpDataPredfor65v.dat};

\addplot [color=black,line width=1pt,densely dashed] table [x=time,y=m08,row sep=newline] {relaxationExpDataPredfor65v.dat};



\end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Generated plot]

I hope you don't need the .dat files called in the code (frankly i am not sure how to upload them, since this is my first question in this community). Thank you in advance for your time!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add `label=above:$\gamma$` in `legend style` definition.

As an example I've used Steven's provided code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            width  = 1*\textwidth,
            height = 4.5cm,
            major x tick style = transparent,
            ybar=1*\pgflinewidth,
            bar width=13pt,
            symbolic x coords={A,B,C,D},
            xtick = data,
            enlarge x limits=0.25,
            ymax=15,
            ymin=0,
            legend cell align=left,
            legend style={
                    at={(1,1.05)},
                    anchor=south east,
                    column sep=1ex,
                    label=above:$\gamma$ %<--------------------
            }
        ]
            \addplot[style={fill=red,mark=none}]
                coordinates {(A, 4.44) (B,0.1) (C,4.37) (D,4.07)};
            \addplot[style={fill=green,mark=none}]
                coordinates {(A, 0.4) (B,0.8) (C,0.3) (D,0.5)};
            \addplot[style={fill=blue,mark=none}]
                coordinates {(A, 0.2) (B,0) (C,0.9) (D,0.8)};
            \addplot[style={fill=yellow,mark=none}]
                coordinates {(A, 9.59) (B,0.2) (C,8.86) (D,8.62)};
        \legend{C1,C2,C3,C4}
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the simple solution. Works perfectly fine.

Comment: @SiddarthVasudevan: You're welcome. I didn't thought it was so easy.

Answer (score 5):

If no answer presents itself inside of `tikz`, here is a way to wrap the code around the outside of the `tikzpicture` environment.  Since I didn't have enough to compile your example, I just grabbed a similar example from another question.

Based completely on the answer at [Annotate grouped bar plot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135786/annotate-grouped-bar-plot/135805#135805), just changing the position of the annotation and the text of it, one can add annotations.  In this MWE, I show two nested annotations: a bullet inside the graph over the red bar; and a gamma over the legend.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{stackengine}[2013-09-11]
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[]
     \stackinset{c}{-3.92cm}{b}{1.52cm}{$\bullet$}{%
     \stackinset{r}{.6cm}{t}{-.3cm}{$\gamma$}{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            width  = 1*\textwidth,
            height = 4.5cm,
            major x tick style = transparent,
            ybar=1*\pgflinewidth,
            bar width=13pt,
            symbolic x coords={A,B,C,D},
            xtick = data,
            enlarge x limits=0.25,
            ymax=15,
            ymin=0,
            legend cell align=left,
            legend style={
                    at={(1,1.05)},
                    anchor=south east,
                    column sep=1ex
            }
        ]
            \addplot[style={fill=red,mark=none}]
                coordinates {(A, 4.44) (B,0.1) (C,4.37) (D,4.07)};
            \addplot[style={fill=green,mark=none}]
                coordinates {(A, 0.4) (B,0.8) (C,0.3) (D,0.5)};
            \addplot[style={fill=blue,mark=none}]
                coordinates {(A, 0.2) (B,0) (C,0.9) (D,0.8)};
            \addplot[style={fill=yellow,mark=none}]
                coordinates {(A, 9.59) (B,0.2) (C,8.86) (D,8.62)};
        \legend{C1,C2,C3,C4}
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
   }}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]