# Plotting a bar graph

Tags: pgfplots

I want to plot a bar graph like below using pgfplot:

[image]

This is a hand drawn pic though. I want to show the change of `r1` and `r2` for a particular variable `a`. For `a=5`, `r1` is measured at `t1` and `t2`, also `r2` is measured at `t1` and `t2`. How can I show this in one plot? I know I can do this in two plots very smoothly. But I dont have enough space in my paper to plot two graphs. Any idea please.

Comment: In this question you may find your answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135786/annotate-grouped-bar-plot

Comment: Please give us at least a minimal document of yours and if possible your first attempts. What does your data look like. Why don't you use a plot graph with error bars which would be the typical approach here. Anyway, please add your two smooth plots and we will help you.

Comment: thanks @Arne. I have got the idea to solve my problem from your given link. I have posted the code below. thanks again.

Comment: @jhon_wick rather new here, the way of thanking here is the upvote an answer ;-)